# Dynamic root is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**I tried using Link and history. I could not access dynamic root and it will not render but the links will change.**

*app.js :*

```
    <>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/login' exact component={Login} />
    <Route path='/verification' exact component={Verification} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/events' component={Events} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/media' component={Media} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/media/:token' component={Post} />
    <Route exact path={["/store", "/store/:cats", "/store/product/:token"]}>
      <StoreLayout>
        <PrivateRoute path='/store' component={Store} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/store/:cats' component={StoreCategory} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/store/product/:token' component={Product} />
      </StoreLayout>
    </Route>
    {showSplash ? <Splash /> : <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Home} />}
  </Switch>
  {alert !== null ? <GeneralAlert alert={alert} /> : null}
  {authAlert !== null ? <AuthAlert alert={authAlert} /> : null}
</>
```

*My problem is that I can not go from Media to Post:*

```
    <PrivateRoute path='/media' component={Media} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/media/:token' component={Post} />
```

*PrivateRoute.jsx :*

```
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router';

const PrivateRoute = ({
  path,
  component: Component,
  redirectTo = '/login',
  exact = true,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { authID: auth, sessionID: session } = useSelector(({ auth }) => auth);
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      exact={exact}
      render={(props) =>
        auth !== null && session !== null ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect from={path} to={redirectTo} />
        )
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

*This is one of the components in Media called MediaContent.jsx where handleClick is located.*

```
 import React from 'react';
import AuthorLogo from '../../../components/Utilities/AuthorLogo';
import AuthorName from '../../../components/Utilities/AuthorName';
import PostTime from '../../../components/Utilities/PostTime';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const MediaContent = ({ post, history }) => {
  const handleClickPost = (e, token) => {
    history.push({
      pathname: '/media/' + token,
      param: token,
    });
  };
  return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => handleClickPost(e, post.token)}
      className='cursor-pointer'>
      <h2 className={`font-bold text-md m-2  px-2`}>{post.title}</h2>

      <div className={`flex justify-between items-center px-2 `}>
        <div className={`flex items-center`}>
          <AuthorLogo logo={post.channel.image} />
          <AuthorName name={post.channel.name} />
        </div>

        <PostTime time={post.datetime} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(MediaContent);
```

*This is what is rendered in index.js:*

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

    render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

Comment: It should probably be history.push({
      pathname:  `/media/&{token}`,
      param: token,
    });

Comment: It should use backticks ""`````````````" those that are inside.